# xampp 1.7.4 + winxp + eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I downloaded the latest Xampp version (1.7.4), installed it under windows XP, disabled the firewall and configured both php.ini and eclipse acording to eclipse installing instructions.

When running phpinfo() function both inside and outside eclipse I see Xdebug loaded but when I try to run debug mode in eclipse it freezes at 57% (waiting for xdebug connection).

In xdebug log I have:

```
Log opened at 2011-06-20 19:38:30
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/test/test.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2912" idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP"><engine version="2.1.0rc1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2010 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2011-06-20 19:38:34
```

The file i was trying to debug is called test.php.

You can view my php.ini here: http://sostudent.com/XAMPP%201.7.4.htm

You can view some screenshots of eclipse config here:

```
> http://sostudent.com/eclipse_servers.JPG
> http://sostudent.com/eclipse_executables.JPG
> http://sostudent.com/eclipse_debuggers.JPG
> http://sostudent.com/eclipse_debug.JPG
```

My php.ini config for xdebug is as follows:

```
[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension ="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\apache\error\xdebug.log"
```

Can someone help?? I can't make sense of this...

Thanks!!

Comment: You have not given any screenshots of the PHP debug view actually. From the log it looks like it ran through OK.

Comment: Sorry... Here it is: http://sostudent.com/eclipse_debug_view.JPG

Comment: From the xdebug.log this looks fine. From the IDE I have no clue. You could try to make eclipse use your normal browser. That will show you the settings eclipse is using within the address field. That might give you a better view what's going on.

Comment: I think I used this howto the first time I got it into action: http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930

Comment: Hey cool you could get it to work ;) I was suspecting some network/port problem yesterday night, but that's hard to say being so far away in a QA page like this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by changing the port I was using to 9005. 9000 didn't work neither 10000 but I don't know why.

Anyway all good now!!

Thanks