# Launching xdebug in Eclipse stuck at 57% - How to trouble-shoot?

Tags: php, eclipse, apache2, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xampp 1.7.4 + winxp + eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416951/xampp-1-7-4-winxp-eclipse)

i am trying to configure a debugger with eclipse for php debugging, but it gets stuck at 57%.
This is my ini file

```
    [XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
; zend_extension_ts="C:xamppphpextphp_xdebug.dll"
; Modify the filename below to reflect the .dll version of your xdebug
zend_extension_ts="C:dev\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.2-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=0
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1  ; if debugging on remote server,
                              ; put client IP here
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:dev\php\tmp"
```

I have changed the port as 9003 as well in eclipse , but stil it gets stuck at 57% always

Comment: Possible related: [xampp 1.7.4 + winxp + eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416951/xampp-1-7-4-winxp-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable it at least:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1 # instead of 0
```

### Troubleshooting xdebug install

#### Check if the xdebug extension is installed

If `phpinfo();` is not listing *xdebug* in the *Configuration* section that lists all installed extensions, then it is not installed. It is important to check this at first, because if the extension is not available, it can not be enabled. Always check this first to not look in the wrong place while trouble-shooting.

The following screen-shot shows how it looks like when it *is* installed:

[image: Successfully installed xdebug extension (Screenshot)]

If your `phpinfo` does not list `xdebug` this means that the extension is not properly loaded.

The [xdebug website](http://xdebug.org) has an especially useful resource for windows (and other) installations called [**the custom installation instructions**](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php). You can copy and paste your `phpinfo();` output into a text-box and it will give you which version/file to download and which `php.ini` to edit. So you will get tailored instructions for your custom set-up.

This should enable you to successfully install the extension so that it can be configured.

Comment: tried it also , changed ports as well still its not working

Comment: i checked xdebug in php info its not there ! looks like xdebug itself not enabled ! how to enable it the path i avce for dll file is correct anything else that shold be done ?

Comment: @kantu: I've updated the answer based on your comment. Please try the custom installation instructions I've linked therein.

Comment: @kantu: Just give an update if you run into a further problem. For windows it's necessary to figure out which kind of extension is needed to be loaded as well (e.g. thread safe or not) and which version for your php version. So let me know if you run into problems even with the custom installation instructions from the xdebug website.