# Install ingres extension for php on my WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, php-extension, ingres

I've a development computer, which runs under windows.

For a project, I've to make a php website which has to connect to an Ingres database server.

So I installed wamp, I installed ingres(server and client, on my local machine).

I added the library that I found on their site(`php_ingres.dll`) in the `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext` folder, and I added a line "`extension=php_ingres.dll`" in the configuration file.

I shutdown wamp and restarted it, and I restarted the server, I see now a check mark in the wamp menu, indicating that php_ingres is now activated. But when I go to the welcome page of the server, I don't see this extension as loaded. If I go on the php info page, I don't see any  Ingres entry in the Configure Command.

I just can't found any `post/tutorial/...` which indicating how to do this operation, so any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit: I made a small test to see if I can connect to an Ingres database:

```
    <?php
$link = ingres_connect("localhost", "demodbtest", "demodbtest")  or die("Connexion impossible");
echo "Connexion réussie";

$result = ingres_query($link,"select * from airline");

while ($row = ingres_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["al_iatacode"];  // utilisation du tableau associatif
    echo $row["al_name"];
    echo $row["al_ccode"];          // utilisation du tableau à indices numériques
    echo "</br>";
}
ingres_close($link);
?>
```

And I get this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function ingres_connect() in
>   C:\wamp\www\tests\index.php on line 2

Some information on my installation:
I've a windows 7 pro 32bits
Wampserver 2.1 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.1/WampServer2.1e-x32.exe/download )
Apache 2.2.17
PHP 5.3.5
Ingres 10.1.0 Community edition( downloaded here: http://esd.ingres.com/product/Community_Projects/Ingres_Database/Windows_32-Bit/Ingres_10.1_Build_121/ingres-10.1.0-121-gpl-win-x86-NoDoc.zip/http )
PHP drivers downloaded here: http://esd.ingres.com/product/drivers/PHP/Windows_32-Bit/PHP_Driver

Comment: Okay, the fatal error means that the extension is not loaded. Which windows version are you using, look as well for 32 or 64bit. The extension must be compatible with your PHP version, so please add a link to the site where you downloaded your WAMP and the extension.

Comment: I added these information on the main post

Comment: Please double check you edited the right PHP.ini file. Then enable error logging to make PHP write errors to a log file. This will log startup errors as well. Check the logfile if PHP complains about loading the extension. Sometimes extensions depend on other extensions, so the order how they appear in the PHP.ini is important (don't know any specifics here for ingres, sorry, so just saying). Hopefully this helps you to get a step ahead.

Comment: I've the 
error_reporting = E_ALL

and my extension=php_ingres.dll is on the last line of the extension references :/

(and I the log file is non-existant when I try to display it through wamp :s)

Comment: Startup errors will only be available in the php error log file. You need to configure it probably. It's a setting within your php.ini. search for `error_log` and give it a path like `c:\phperror.log`. You should then find that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I wasn't having the ingres client installed locally, so it appears that this lib cannot works without it

Answer (score 0):

To practically test if the extension was loaded you can as well call one of it's functions. If the extension was loaded, you should not get a fatal error for a missing function. That's perhaps one of the quickest checks.

Another check is to make use of [`extension_loaded` <sup>*PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/extension_loaded) which will give you a list of all loaded extensions. See the PHP Manual link above for more info.

#### The configure line

The configure line will not show the ingres extension because it has not been compiled in. That's perfectly alright because you load it as an extension (`.dll`) so it's not part of `php.exe`. This is why you don't see it in the configure line.

#### Locating `ingres` on the phpinfo() page.

On the `phpinfo()`-page use the search function inside your browser (often `CTRL+F`) and try to locate the word `ingres`. You should locate a section that displays the extensions default settings if it has been loaded.

The following is an example screenshot for the xdebug extension. This might look similar for ingres:

[image: Successfully installed xdebug extension (Screenshot)]
Image from: [Launching xdebug in Eclipse stuck at 57% - How to trouble-shoot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423153/launching-xdebug-in-eclipse-stuck-at-57-how-to-trouble-shoot/6423302)

Comment: Good to know, but the only place where I can find "ingres" is in environnement variable in path.

I forgot to mention that I've made a small test, I edit my post right now

Comment: okay you're calling from commandline. that's probably more easy/quickly for figuring out what's wrong. `php --re ingres` should give you an error as well until the extension is available. Use `php --ini` to display the ini files and check yours is in there. If it is it means the extension is not loading, which either is a wrong configuration or the extension can not be loaded. the php error log is helpful then.

Comment: I double-checked, I've only one php.ini file, which is in the same folder than the php.exe(used for the CLI and the web execution)

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `extension_dir` setting as well as the actual `php.ini` file being used. Calling `php.exe -i` from the command line might not give the same output if executing `phpinfo()` in a script via Apache (or IIS). In fact http://www.wampserver.com/en/faq.php says there are 3 potential `php.ini` scripts.

Comment: I opened the one which is displayed by wamp when I click on the php.ini item in the wamp menu, so I suppose it's the good one(and wamp see it checked)

Comment: in addition, I added another extension(support of mssql), in the same configuration file, and it works, so I suppose I'm editing the good file

Comment: so if you execute ´php -c <path to php.ini> -m´ you don't see ingres listed?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\julien>C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe -c C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
com_dotnet
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlsrv
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug


C:\Users\julien>

Comment: So no, there is no ingres loaded

Comment: Is there a php_ingres.dll located in the directory for:

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe -c C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini -r "ini_get('extension_dir');"

and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini contains the line:

extension=php_ingres.dll